# Bounded Convergence Theorem and vanishing functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am studying Real Analysis by Stein and I don't understand how to interpret the word "vanish", which is used informally in the bounded convergence theorem (Theorem 1.4, pg 56). Here is the theorem for reference and the surrounding comments about it.

> Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions that are all bounded by $M$, are supported on a set $E$ of finite measure, and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. $x$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $f$ is measurable, bounded, supported on $E$ for a.e. $x$ and as $n \to \infty$, $$\int |f_n - f| \to 0$$ and $$\int f_n \to \int f$$

Parts of the discussion on the theorem:

- *From the assumption one sees at once that $f$ is bounded by $M$ almost everywhere and **vanishes** outside $E$, except possibly on a set of measure zero.*

What does vanish mean? I think that $f$ "vanishes" to 0 outside of $E$. It gets small and "vanishes" to 0, but then I don't understand the exception on why $f$ wouldn't vanish on a set of measure zero so I see my thinking is flawed, but I don't get how. Is my intuition about vanishing completely wrong?

Comment: It means that $f$ is $0$ outside $E$ (except ...).

Comment: so f is 0 outside of E except possibly on a measure zero? That makes sense. Is there a simple example to see where $f$ is not 0 on a set of measure zero?

Comment: It means that with the exception of a set of measure zero, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in E^c$. The boundary of the set may have exceptional points.

Comment: are the exceptional points the points where$f_n$ does not converge uniformly "almost everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It's because $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e. So lets consider a more specific example. Len $E=[-1,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on the line. Let's consider $f_n$ are supported on $[-1,1]$ and $f$ is the the pointwise limit and lets say that $f$ vanishes outside of $E$. Then if $g(x):=f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q\cap E}$ and $g(x) :=f(x)+1=1$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q\cap E}$, then $f_n\to g$ a.e. as well.

Comment: ohhh I think I get it. Uniform convergence only applies "almost everywhere" and not "everywhere". So the set of points that are outside of "almost everywhere" are the exception

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you said. Uniform convergence is a different thing from converging in $L^1$ or the integral of $f_n$ to converge to the integral of $f$. What I'm saying is that basically the a.e.-pointwise limit of $f_n$, lets say $f$, can be replaced by a $g$ so that $f=g$ a.e. and we still have that $f_n\to g$ a.e. and of course $\int f=\int g$.